# How to generalize the integral invariant property: $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-r^2}dr = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-(r+t)^2}dr $

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The following equation holds for all $t \in \mathbb R$. 
$$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-r^2}dr = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-(r+t)^2}dr $$
I'm trying to extend the invariant property to a general unbounded set $\mathcal R$, on which a measure $\mu$ is defined, such as $\mathcal R$ is the set of all the $m*n$ column orthonormal matrices. The corresponding equation is shown in the following. 
$$ \int_{\mathcal R} e^{-f(r)^2}\mu(dr) = \int_{\mathcal R} e^{-(f(r)+t)^2}\mu(dr)$$
My question is: what properties of the real valued function $f(r)$, the measure $\mu$, and the set $\mathcal R$ should have in order to have the above equation for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Very creative nickname!

Comment: @BingBang  Somehow  related to your post:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581967/is-int-m-n-mathbbr-e-a2d-mu-a-convergent-integral2